# Changing CLARA cluster plot scale

Tags: r, linux, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am using [factoextra](https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/factoextra/index.html) and CLARA method for my clustering and the plot looks like this.

This is my plot:

[image]

How can I change the scale so the upper clusters don't look squeezed like that?

Also, how can I remove that one cluster for the plotting?

My code for the plot:

```
fviz_cluster(clara.res,
             palette = c("#fcff00",
                         "#ffb14e",
                         "#51ff38",
                         "#a30000",
                         "#ffc8ff",
                         "#9d02d7",
                         "#1000e5",
                         "#12890b",
                         "#00c1ff"), # color palette
             ellipse.type = "t", # Concentration ellipse
             geom = "point", pointsize = 1,
             ggtheme = theme_classic())
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming plot is a ggplot object, try adding: `... + ylim(-5, 5)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks. It didn't work with ylim.  Now I also get a warning

In MASS::cov.trob(data[, vars]) : Probable convergence failure

Comment: Oh now it works! Thank you!